# How can I align an absolutely-positioned element to the right with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position, absolute

I was working on a landing page but I got a problem, cant move the collapse button from left to right. One of the problems is position-absolute. I don't wanna remove it but I don't know any replacement for that. Could someone help me?

```
<div class="h-100">
    <video id="videolayout" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="resources/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark position-absolute">
        <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto float-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText"
        aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button> <!-- button I got problem with -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-2">
                <!-- just list items -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container text-white h-100">
        <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <h3 class="font-weight-bold">h3 test</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body{ //css
    height: 100%;
}

#videolayout{
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: do you want to move this button to the right? - https://ibb.co/72T12nz

Comment: If you are using `position-absolute` you have to specify a width (ex. `w-100`). If you just want the nav affixed to the top use `fixed-top`